# How to create customized google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for information about how to create customized google map for Android. This question came into my head after I saw the Ingress game app. Does anyone of you know, how map work work in this application ?

I've read that you can create your own customized map using Maps Api v3 on Web and display it using WebView, but this doesn't seems to work like this.

Ingress on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticproject.ingress

Answer (score 0):

Style Map feature is for you :)
have a look https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: another example for customize google map https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map